# Azure disk size too small. Linux basic A0 only 29GB

Tags: azure

I have just created a linux (Ubuntu 14.4) virtual machine in Azure (SE Asia)

*Issue: I only have 29GB not 127GB*

It is a Basic Tier, A0 (smallest size)

The advertised disk drive size is **127GB** (+20GB tmp)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn197896.aspx

I find (after running out of disk space) that I only have around **29GB**.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        29G   24G  4.1G  86% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            323M   12K  323M   1% /dev
tmpfs            68M  388K   67M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            336M     0  336M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sdb1        20G  4.3G   15G  23% /mnt
```

Running `cfdisk` shows there is no other free space on the drive.

I can't find any documentation to suggest why only 29GB.

Is this a bug/issue/problem with my VM?

Or is it something to do with linux/ubuntu 14.4/basic tier A0 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The VM's operating system drive is backed by a blob in your Azure storage account.  The blob is a VHD file.  When you created the VM, the appropriate VHD was copied from the gallery into your storage account.

The gallery-provided VHD file has a logical capacity of 30GB by design.   The documentation states that the maximum allowed size is 127GB, but that is incidental - the gallery images are 30GB.

The solution is two steps, resize the VHD itself (and corresponding blob), then use Linux tooling to resize the partition. This may help:

[Resizing a Windows Azure virtual disk](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2013/01/07/Tales-from-the-trenches-resizing-a-Windows-Azure-virtual-disk-the-smooth-way.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Eron.  I just found this post too which explains this too. It would be great if the setup process described the disk available in the gallery image.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/cc182eba-e740-40b3-b05d-91fe69749070/confused-about-vm-storage-size

Answer (score 3):

It's now possible to resize via the Azure UI.

That being said, after resizing, the Ubuntu VM will not see the new size by default, you will see that `cfdisk` sees the unallocated space, and to do it I would use `fdisk` like it's explained in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/119458).

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute follow `Azure PowerShell` command:

```
Update-AzureDisk –DiskName "<Disk name>" -Label "ResiZedOS" -ResizedSizeInGB <Size in GB>
```

Example:

```
Update-AzureDisk –DiskName "dimitar-linux-dimitar-linux-os" -Label "ResiZedOS" -ResizedSizeInGB 524
```

**Note**: Maximum size is 1023 GB.

**Note 2**: Virtual machine should be power off.

Documentation:

- [How to install and configure Azure PowerShell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/#step-1-install)
- [Update-AzureVM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495230.aspx)
- [Update-AzureDisk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495123.aspx)

> **Question**: How to get disk name ?
>
> **Answer**: You can use azure cli or azure portal.

`azure-cli` command:

```
azure vm disk list <virtual machine name> # In my case: azure vm disk list dimitar-centos
```

[image: Example azure cli output]

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [Eron Wright's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23299211/813821), the disk's size is determined from the Gallery image.

To resize the disk via the Azure Portal web UI:

1. Shut down (deallocate) the VM.
2. Open the VM blade and click Disks
3. Select the OS disk. For me, the size of the disk was blank.
4. Enter a new Size and click Save.

I tested this with an `Standard_D2_V2` sized Ubuntu VM. Once I resized the disk and started the VM, I could access the full size of the disk.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @danailov work brilliantly for me (Azure Linux VM resized correctly)

Just to add this bit that might help somebody; here is how I found out my disk name via Azure Powershell;

```
Get-AzureDisk | Get-AzureDisk | Format-list  DiskName, AttachedTo, DiskSizeInGB, OS > c:\files\disks.txt
```

The above command will output a text file at the stated location in your local pc with following details for each disks/VMs in your Azure account - DiskName, AttachedTo, DiskSizeInGB and OS the VM is running.